# Show that $con_H^g$ is the identity map

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group,$H$ a subgroup of $G$ and $A$ be $G$-module. Let $g \in G$ and $H^g=g^{-1}Hg$. Let $Z^2(G,A)$ be the set of $2$-cocycles. Given $f \in Z^2(H,A)$, let $f^g \in Z^2(H^g,A)$ be defined by $f^g(x,y)=f(gxg^{-1},gyg^{-1})$ for all $x,y \in H$. Then the map from $Z^2(H,A) \rightarrow Z^2(H^g,A)$ defined by$f \mapsto f^g$ induces a map on the cohomology $H^2(H,A) \rightarrow H^2(H^g,A)$. This is denoted by $Con_H^g$.

How can I show that if $g \in H$, then $con_H^g$ is the identity map.

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the calculation I did in my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622976 taking $G=H$? If you want a reference, it's Propn 8.3 of Kenneth S. Brown's book "Cohomology of Groups", but the treatment there is very abstract.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you very much for your prompt reply.